# How to define a Typescript constructor and factory function with the same name?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am writing a Typescript definition file for an [existing Javascript library](https://github.com/RubenVerborgh/N3.js).
In this library there are functions which can be called as constructors or factories.
How do I write the typings in a compatible fashion?

Here is a specific example of the calls that [need to be supported according to the README](https://github.com/RubenVerborgh/N3.js/blob/master/README.md):

```ts
var streamParser = N3.StreamParser();
var streamParser = new N3.StreamParser();
```

My current approach is to only support the factory.

```ts
function Parser(options?: ParserOptions): N3Parser;
```

The obvious approach to get the `new` to work is to create a class.

```ts
class Parser {
  constructor(options ? : ParserOptions);
}
```

But these two approaches are incompatible.
The opening paragraph of the [declartion-file deep-dive](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/deep-dive.html) indicates this is possible but no example is given.

Note:
The following two definitions are compatible but... so, what?

```ts
interface Parser {
  new: (options ? : ParserOptions) => N3Parser;
}

function Parser(options ? : ParserOptions): N3Parser;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow the same thing that is done in the [lib.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts) with [Array](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L1126) and [ArrayConstructor](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L1290):

```
interface Parser {}

interface ParserConstructor {
    new (options?: ParserOptions): Parser;
    (options?: ParserOptions): Parser;
}

declare const Parser: ParserConstructor;

let p1 = Parser();
let p2 = new Parser();
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20N3Parser%20%7B%20%7D%0Ainterface%20ParserOptions%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20Parser%20%7B%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20ParserConstructor%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20new%20(options%3F%3A%20ParserOptions)%3A%20Parser%3B%0A%20%20%20%20(options%3F%3A%20ParserOptions)%3A%20Parser%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Adeclare%20const%20Parser%3A%20ParserConstructor%3B%0A%0Alet%20p1%20%3D%20Parser()%3B%0Alet%20p2%20%3D%20new%20Parser()%3B))

Answer (score 0):

Nitzan Tomer's answer is spot-on.

For my particular case the object constructed has an different interface and the constructor needs some overloading.
The following sample shows how the constructor interface can easily support these requirements.

```
interface N3Parser { }
interface ParserOptions {[key: string]: string }

interface ParserConstructor {
    new (options?: ParserOptions): N3Parser;
    (options?: ParserOptions): N3Parser;

    new (fd: any, options?: ParserOptions): N3Parser;
    (fd: any, options?: ParserOptions): N3Parser;
}
declare const Parser: ParserConstructor;

let p1 = Parser();
let p2 = new Parser();

let p3 = Parser({ x: "y" });
let p4 = new Parser(3, { x: "y" });
```